# Specify Python 3 to not meddle with new line?

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code in Python 3:

```
st = "a" + '\r\n\r\n\r\n' + "b"
print( st )
```

The output is the following:

[image]

I do not want Python to add a 'CR' for me - I need to be in control. Is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

The built-in method `repr()` will return the string without the newline formatting.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr

```
>>> st = "a" + '\r\n\r\n\r\n' + "b"
>>> print(repr(st))
'a\r\n\r\n\r\nb'
```

Alternatively, you can use a *raw string* like as demonstrated below.
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

```
>>> print("a" + r'\r\n\r\n' + "b")
a\r\n\r\nb
```

Answer (score 0):

Except the last one, all others are there just because you are telling python to write them (\r for LF and \n for CR). If you refer to the CR LF then you can use:

```
print(st,end="\n")
```